# Excluir variables de ciertos eventos

Tags: sql, postgresql

me gustaria saber si estoy empleando la lógica correcta en mi código, tengo variables que representan eventos(fechas) y otras que representas resultados y se me ha pedido que excluyan ciertas variables de ciertos eventos, ej: tengo la misma variable en todos los eventos pues solo coloco que sea diferente a esa variable y ya pero cuando la variable solo la debo excluir de ciertos eventos hago esto ( variable != variable and evento =!evento), este es el código

```
...and sd.item_group_oid != 'g_codingresult' 
      and sd.form_oid not in ('f_pre_fast', 'f_cov','f_randomization','f_cov_vac','f_diary_imp_v1'
      'f_diary_imp_v2','f_diary_imp_v3','f_diary_imp_v4','f_diary_imp_v5','f_diary_imp_v6','f_diary_disp',
      'f_ex_analysis')
      and (sd.form_oid != 'f_diary_ret' and sd.event_oid != 'e_v7' and  sd.event_oid != 'e_v4' )
```

La primera exclusión no me preocupa porque esas variables estan en todos los eventos y de todos se tiene que excluir pero la segunda es un elemento que solo debo omitir en ciertos eventos que no sean la visita 7 y la visita 4 y de cierta manera siento que estoy mal porque si meto asi los eventos creo que los estoy excluyendo igual de todo

---

Creo que la forma correcta sería esta, pero igual me gustaría confimar si mi lógica es correcta:

```
and sd.item_group_oid != 'g_codingresult' 
      and sd.form_oid not in ('f_pre_fast', 'f_cov','f_randomization','f_cov_vac','f_diary_disp',
      'f_ex_analysis','f_disp_imp')
      and ((sd.event_oid not in ('e_v2', 'e_v3', 'e_v5', 'e_v8', 'e_v9', 'e_v10', 'e_v11', 'e_v12', 'e_v13'))
      or (sd.event_oid in ('e_v2', 'e_v3', 'e_v5', 'e_v8', 'e_v9', 'e_v10', 'e_v11', 'e_v12', 'e_v13') and sd.form_oid != 'f_diary_ret'))
```